# Question related to chapter styles

Tags: chapters

I want to obtain the style of my chapters like the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\rhead{\textbf{\thepage}}
\lhead{\textsl{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}%
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Thanks}
\chapter{Chapter one}

\begin{thebibliography}{999} 
\newpage
\bibitem{axlupol}{O. Axelsson, H. Lu, B. Polman,} {On the numerical radius of matrices and its application to iterative solution methods,} Linear Multilinear Algebra 37 (1994) 225-238. 
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

My goal is to obtain

[image]

Comment: Template #39 of [LaTeX examples](http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/LaTeX_samples_chapter/0.html).

Comment: @DũngVũ It doen't compilate.

Comment: I'm sorry for the incompilablity. I usually use that site to have my chapters designed, but I haven't tried that template. I'm finding some other ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An attempt using Ti*k*Z:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\titleformat{\chapter}{}{}{0pt}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill[black] (-0.7,-2) rectangle (0.7,2);
        \draw[color=white] (0,1) node {\bfseries\Huge\thechapter};
        \draw (0,2.5) node {\Large Chapter};
        \draw (1,0)--(13,0);
        \coordinate (start) at (1,0);
        \node[below right=5mm and 0cm of start.center] {\bfseries\Huge #1};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You should not use `\chapter*{}` as it doesn't work! Instead, try this code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\titleformat{\chapter}{}{}{0pt}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill[black] (-0.7,-1.5) rectangle (0.7,1.5);
        % Change to \fill (-0.7,-2) rectangle (0.7,2); if you want the black rectangle to be longer
        \draw[color=white] (0,0.5) node {\bfseries\Huge\thechapter};
        % Change to (0,1) if the black rectangle is changed in \fill
        \draw (0,2) node {\Large Chapter};
        % Change to (0,2.5) if the black rectangle is changed in \fill
        \draw (1,0)--(13,0);
        \coordinate (start) at (1,0);
        \node[below right=5mm and 0cm of start.center] {\bfseries\Huge #1};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\newpage
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[black] (-0.7,-1.5) rectangle (0.7,1.5);
        % Change to \fill (-0.7,-2) rectangle (0.7,2); if you want the black rectangle to be longer
        \draw (1,0)--(13,0);
        \coordinate (start) at (1,0);
        \node[below right=5mm and 0cm of start.center] {\bfseries\Huge Thanks!};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Though you will add a piece of code which is not so short, but I think it is Ok. Because when the `\chapter` is defined in this way, `\thechapter` is placed in the Ti*k*Z picture, so `\chapter*` loses its own function.

*If you can improve my answer to a better one, your edit, or, rather, **your** answer will be high appreciated!*

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If for axample I want to write `\chapter*{Introduction}` and I want that the number of chapter doen't appear, how can I do?

Comment: @Student How will the chapter look like if you use `\chapter*`? I think the chapter would look bad if there isn't the number.

Comment: @Student Yes! I am editing my answer.

Comment: @Student I already edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. How can I reduce the height of the black rectangle or you think that the height is good?

Comment: @Student You can edit the x-coordinate and y-coordinate of points in `\fill`. That will change the size of the black rectangle